# how to add/make the view visible under a scrollView?

Tags: iphone, xcode, sdk, uiscrollview, xib

I'm partially through adding a scrollview, by way of instantiating a class that subclasses uiscrollview (below called ScrollViewManager) to override touchesEnded. The problem is although my class now has scrolling and touch, I can't see my view/nib file anymore, even though it's responding to touches and scrolling fine.

My thoughts are to add back the MyClass nib as a subview? or don't know... Seems as though it's there but just hidden behind this scrollView.

The excerpt from 'Myclass : UIViewController ' has these lines of code in viewDidLoad to get the scroll action with touch response.

Thank you so much. So so much.

```
scrollView = [[ScrollViewManager alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame]; 
scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 600);
[scrollView setUserInteractionEnabled:TRUE];
[scrollView setScrollEnabled:TRUE];
self.view = scrollView;

//trying with this line to add my nib for this class on top of the scroll view
    //which doesn't work: 'Accessing unknown 'view' class method'
[scrollView addSubview:Myclass.view];
    [scrollView release];
```

Answer (score 1):

self.view = scrollView line makes your view pointed by view controllers the scrollview.
ie self.view & scrollView now point to same object

after that when you are trying to [scrollView addSubview:Myclass.view]; what actually happening is you are adding scrollView to your scrollView & accessing view property of scrollview.

Just remove the self.view = scrollView line & do this

```
[self.view addSubView:scrollView];
[scrollView release];
```

Hopefully it'll work.

Answer (score 0):

for some reason I can't add comments to your post.  It didn't work.
Apple talks about adding the subview [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/UIScrollView_pg/CreatingBasicScrollViews/CreatingBasicScrollViews.html): but doesn't explain how.  Their code is below for adding the scroll aspect, as I did above. I'm now messing around with trying to add my view as a subview:

```
 UIView *newView = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyClassView" owner:self options: nil];
[scrollView addSubview:newView];
```

but that crashes and goes not where.  Don't know what to do now. Apple's code here with original comments:

```
  (void)loadView {
    CGRect fullScreenRect=[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];
    scrollView=[[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:fullScreenRect];
    self.view=scrollView;
    scrollView.contentSize=CGSizeMake(320,758);
    scrollView.contentInset=UIEdgeInsetsMake(64.0,0.0,44.0,0.0);


// do any further configuration to the scroll view
// add a view, or views, as a subview of the scroll view.

// release scrollView as self.view retains it
self.view=scrollView;
[scrollView release];
```

}

Comment: Are you releasing newView? If yes then you shouldn't.

Comment: No I don't release it. I also abandoned that approach unfruitful. After more playing around I noticed that I can add textfields, etc. in the code and they'd show up and work with the scroll still in effect.  Problem is I have about 30 items that handle a lot of interaction, so I'm very reluctant to go down that path.  Seems just strange and depressing I just can't add the view I already made (and works minus scrolling with touch). Any other suggestions extremely welcomed. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Just noticed that I can add each of my nib components as a subview and they keep their functionality.  So if worse comes to worse, that may be a workaround.  Still get the feeling I could have one line of code to solve the original problem.  That magic line...